# Convert JSON String to JSON Array in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a JSON string in rails  as shown below:

```
[{"content":"1D","createdTime":"09-06-2011 00:59"},{"content":"2D","createdtime":"09-06-2011 08:00"}]
```

which are the objects of a class content with attributes content and created time.

I would like to **convert this JSON string to its respective JSON object array** so that I can run a loop and decode the JSON to its objects in rails. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the json library [json](http://flori.github.com/json/)

You can then do:

```
jsonArray = [{"content":"1D","createdTime":"09-06-2011 00:59"},   
              {"content":"2D","createdtime":"09-06-2011 08:00"}]
objArray = JSON.parse(jsonArray)
```

In response to your comment, you can do this, as long as your JSON fits your model

```
objArray.each do |object|
  # This is a hash object so now create a new one.
  newMyObject = MyObject.new(object)
  newMyObject.save # You can do validation or any other processing around here.
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy.Will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Thanks jeremy.It worked .But after I got the objArray.I tried doing 
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(objArray[0]) .It gave me this error 
Type Error:can't convert hash to string

Comment: There is no need, JSON parse already turned it into an array of Ruby objects.

Comment: So if I do Content.new(objArray[0]) .Would it create the object?I wanted to insert the content object into the database..

Comment: Your example of the string jsonArray gives me a syntax error when I copy and paste it into the rails console.

Comment: It's the extra quotes around the array. jsonArray should be an array not a string, I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 41):

`ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(string)` will decode that for you into a delicious consumable object on the server side.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then if you already knew this.

Comment: Didn't know how to convert from json string to json array in rails :-).Tat was my question

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript code is internal then you can do this:

```
<script>
    var hives = <%=@hives.html_safe%>;
</script>
```

**Otherwise:**

create hidden textarea and set **@hives.html_safe** as its value now you can get it in JavaScript as element's value as shown below:

**In html.erb file**

```
<%= text_area_tag :hives_yearly_temp, @hives.html_safe, { style: "display: none;"} %>
```

**In js file**

```
var hives = JSON.parse( $('#hives_yearly_temp').val() );
```

**To run loop**

```
for(key in hives) {
  alert( hives[key] );
}
```